# Valuable inventory framed Site

Tags: admob, adsense, sites

this violation occurs on my android apps when i make some changes or reduce some ads then the google passed it and said the issue is fixed after some days they strive again that the Violation is occurred what should i do now

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue arises from WebView where other sites also shows ads in the form of banner or full screen ads.

> AdSense is for original content you created, it is not for lists of
>   links to other sites.

So use Adblock in your WebView and done. then try your own ads in your app.